# XPath test value of grandchild element?

Tags: xml, xpath

If a query returns this XML

```
<hudson>
    <job>
        <displayName>test1</displayName>
        <url>https://something/test1</url>
        <lastBuild>
            <building>true</building>
            <builtOn>server1</builtOn>
        </lastBuild>
    </job>
    <job>
        <displayName>test2</displayName>
        <url>https://something/test2</url>
        <lastBuild>
            <building>false</building>
            <builtOn>server1</builtOn>
        </lastBuild>
    </job>
    <job>
        <displayName>test3</displayName>
        <url>https://something/test3
        </url>
        <lastBuild>
            <building>true</building>
            <builtOn>server2</builtOn>
        </lastBuild>
    </job>
    <job>
        <displayName>test4</displayName>
        <url>https://something/test4</url>
    </job>
    <job>
        <displayName>test5</displayName>
        <url>https://something/test5</url>
    </job>
</hudson>
```

How can I further filter with xpath to get only the jobs where the tag `building` is true and exclude those where the tag `lastBuild` does not exists?

For the first option I use

```
&xpath=/hudson/job/lastBuild[contains(building,'true')]
```

But not sure how to get rid of those without the tag `lastBuild`...

Comment: "lastBuild" does not exist? Are you sure this is what you are asking? I ask this because your result will only return those elements named lastBuild.. so that by itself seems to have excluded those that does not have lastBuild...

Comment: How would you do the xpath query then? I want to get exactly the same information but only of those jobs where lastBuild/building==true

Comment: you are already doing that... it seems to me... have you examined the output of this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the XML that you show, this XPath,

```
/hudson/job[lastBuild/building = 'true']
```

will select those `job` elements with `lastBuild` elements where `building` is `true`:

```
<job> 
    <displayName>test1</displayName>  
    <url>https://something/test1</url>  
    <lastBuild> 
      <building>true</building>  
      <builtOn>server1</builtOn> 
    </lastBuild> 
</job>
<job> 
    <displayName>test3</displayName>  
    <url>https://something/test3</url>  
    <lastBuild> 
      <building>true</building>  
      <builtOn>server2</builtOn> 
    </lastBuild> 
</job>
```

Comment: That´s what I was looking for. I used the "[ ] " in the wrong place. Thanks!